# Plupload Resize and Upload at once

Tags: php, plupload

I have using Plupload to upload images, but now I need a thumbnail of the images too.

I know how the resize works in Plupload but I need it to upload the original file, then the RESIZED thumnail of the image, so I need both of them.

My final aim is to get the original picture and a thumnail for ex.:
picture.jpg
_picture.jpg

The _ means that is a thumbnail.

I have tried many ways (for ex.: cwUpload worked well, but I cant call it with the pictures)

I have tried to make duplicaton var uploader2 = new plupload.Uploader({..}) and make only the resize but not worked.
My idea is was) to combine a plupload upload then a plupload resize upload somehow.

Can you help me a bit how to reach it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should accept uploading the original image and resize it afterwards, if the upload was successful.

I've implemented such a function in my own project.

Look here: https://github.com/OpenBookCase/OpenBookCase/blob/master/lib/API.php#L389